# HDLC encoding protocol

Tags: encoding, serial-port, checksum, network-protocols, rs485

I will have to use the HDLC protocol on a synchronous RS485, but I don't understand the encoding algorithm very well.

If I have, for example, this condition:

- Address: 0x01 (1 byte)
- Control: 0x02 (1 byte)
- Data arary: [0]0x03 [1]0x04 [2]0xFF [3]0x05 [4]0x06 [5]0x07 (6 byte)
- FCS: 0xC8A1 (2 byte) (calculated CRC-CCITT 16bit HDLC)

**1)** Is the FCS correct (0xC8A1)? (I calculated the FCS on Address, Control and Data: "0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04 0xFF 0x05 0x06 0x07")

**2)** Which is the HDLC packet correct?

- "0x7E 0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04 0xFF 0x05
  0x06 0x07 C8 A1 0x7E"
- "0x7E 0x01 0x02 0x07 0x06 0x05 0xFF
  0x04 0x03 A1 C8    0x7E" (Reverse data)

**3)** Whitch is the "bit train" before applying the "bit stuffing method"? (referring to the first example above)

- 00000001 00000010 00000011 00000100 11111111 00000101 00000110
  00000111 11001000 10100001
- 10000000 01000000 11000000 00000011 11111111 10100000 01100000
  11100000 00010011 10000101 (Reverse all bits)

**4)** Is correct, for the "bit stuffing method" start from the left?: (referring to the first example above)

- 00000001 00000010 00000011 00000100 11111111 00000101 00000110
  00000111 11001000 10100001
- result: 00000001 00000010 00000011 00000100 11111011 10000010
  10000011 00000011 11100010 00101000 01000000 (added two 0 bits (after
  5 1bit) and added 0 bits for complete the byte on the right)

**5)** Is the correct order for send the data on RS485? (referring to the first example above after bit stuffing)

- 00000001 00000010 00000011 00000100 11111011 10000010 10000011
  00000011 11100010 00101000 01000000

  [0]0x7E 
  [1]0x01
  [2]0x02
  [3]0x03
  [4]0x04
  [5]0xFB
  [6]0x82
  [7]0x83
  [8]0x03
  [9]0xE2
  [10]0x28
  [11]0x40
  [12]0x7E

thank you